# How does Firebase FireStore Read Count works? Does it relay on Document? or Document Field? of Document Field Data?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app using Firestore as a database and am a bit confused about firestore reads, I ma how does it count 1 read?

**1.** If whenever I call any document from the collection, does this document read cost me as 1 read?
note: the document has 10 string fields with data
so does it cost me 1 read? (document read) or 10 read? because am calling 10 fields of that document as well.

**2.** if document call doesn't consider as 1 read, then in the second stage am calling 10 string fileds of a document as well, so now does it consider as 10 reads?

```
if (value.contains("full_name")) {Bollen FullName = true;}
```

Note: In this stage, I am calling string field like this, which means if the field exists in the document then that's it I continue my next task. (Make sure that I haven't used **stFullName = value.getString("full_name");** here, just checked that does field exists here or not?)
So does it cost me as 1 read per 1 field, in total 10 reads?

**3.** Here I have the 3rd stage, where I am calling document with its 10 string field with 1 additional thing

```
if (value.contains("full_name")) {String stFullNameX = value.getString("full_name");}
```

Now here I am getting the string data from the field as well this time, does this 1 call per string field will be considered as 1 read? and calling 10 string field data **value.getString** in the string will cost me 10 reads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) it says that Firestore charges for **document** reads (emphasis mine). So it charges your project each time it has to retrieve a document from/on the server.

If you [load a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) (so call `get()` on a `DocumentReference` to get a `DocumentSnapshot`), that counts as one document read regardless of home many fields there are in the document. The number of fields *does* affect the size of the document though, so the bandwidth charges will be depend on the number of fields and the size of the data in there.

There is no charge for accessing a field in the `DocumentSnapshot`. So once you have the `DocumentSnapshot`, it doesn't matter how often you access the fields in there.

If you [load a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) multiple times with that same API, you will be charged one document read for each time you load the document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
1 more question, If I request a snapshot of a document (in device 1) and my snapshot is active and in the same document data will be changed from another device (device 2), so my device 1 data will be updated within sec, at this time, due to snapshot, data changed, does it like as 1 new document call and i will be charged as 1 new read? or it wont be charged on me after only 1st document request?

Comment: That would require a realtime listener, which I intentionally skipped above. But the logic is similar: since the document needs to be read for that client on/from the server, you are charged 1 document read (+ any bandwidth charged for the data in that document) for the update too.

Comment: Okay got it, you mean I will be charged every time as 1 document read whenever new data coming in my device, either its from new request or its auto snapshot.
Am I Right?